# Put name of layer collision is detected with in Debug Log

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a game where I imported a tilemap into unity using tiled2unity.

Everything worked fine except that, may player is colliding but I cant seem to figure out what it's colliding with.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Collision Occured");


        if (col.gameObject.tag == "TileLayer1") 
        {

            Debug.Log ("Collision Occured With Layr");

            isJumping = false;
            isJumping2 = false;
        }
    }
```

Looking at the code above, when my character lands, the message "Collision Occured" is registered. but I cannot get it to show "Collision Occured With Layr".

Given that a collision is occuring on the OnCollisionEntere2D method, is there a way that I can log the names of the two bodies?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what are you looking for, but from what I understood you want to find out what bodies are colliding - you can just

```
Debug.Log(col.transform.name)
```

That way you can track which object may be in between.